# Hide global window.google.maps object with AMD

Tags: javascript, google-maps, amd

I'm using the AMD module pattern and until now, it has been relatively simple to hide what would otherwise be global objects:

```
define([], function(){

  /*jquery here */

  var tmp = $;
  $ = undefined;
  return tmp;
}
```

However, I'm curious if it's possible to do something similar with google's global objects (I guess they're really into these.. maps and pretty much any of its APIs use em).

Just doing what I've done before actually breaks the code because. It seems internally google is self referencing itself with calls to the global window.google object from scripts it loads on the fly.

I'm going to keep investigating but am curious what you all think!

Thanks.

Comment: Depending on which google stuff -- load in an iFrame?

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher use google maps as the example. I would like to reference the maps API but I would like to do so using the AMD pattern. So an iframe seems tricky here but I'm not too familiar with how to use them effectively maybe you could shed some light.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) as your AMD loader, you can use [config shims](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) to wrap non-AMD modules, express their dependencies, perform any necessary initializations (where you *could* clear their global, if the script supports it) and export their global.

For Google Maps, this would look something like this (and no, you probably don't want to clear the global google variable):

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "maps": "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY"
    },
    shims: {
        "maps": {
            exports: "google.maps"
        }
    }
});
```

Later on, you can use this as a regular AMD module:

```
require(["maps"], function(maps) {
   var map = new maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), ....);
   ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I do use RequireJS. Is this anything more than just a standard way of doing what I'd done manually above in code? It still leaves window.google which may be something I have to live with I just want to fully understand.

Comment: It is pretty much the same thing you're trying to do in code, except that it also allows you to specifify prerequisites.  This is not an issue for Google maps, but might be for a script that expects another script to be loaded first.  I'm not sure whether it's safe to remove the google global variable or whether the maps script depends on its presence.  If you wanted to remove it, you would do so by specifying an init() method in the shim.

Comment: Also, your jQuery example doesn't actually remove the $ variable from the global scope (you're clearing the local $).  FWIW, jQuery 1.7 and later can already be loaded as an AMD module (you can google it).  In any case, the proper way to remove jQuery's global $ is to call jQuery.noConflict().

Comment: Good call I just threw that example up without thinking! I've edited to make actual sense. It's just an example as I know jQuery is a great library with actual support, many libraries are less so.